# Show Cross image on out of stock product in default swatches

Tags: image, magento-1.9

How i can show an cross image on out of stock item in default color swatches in Magento 1.9

For example if we have Product with these  two attribute

1) Size 8|9|10

2) Color Green | Yellow | Magento

And suppose if product with size 8 and color green is out of stock then when we choose size 8 and color green then size image must be show as a crossed image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but I think that you'll achieve what you want by modifying line 151 of Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable:

```
if(!$this->_validateAttributeValue($attributeId, $value, $options)) {
   $inStock = false;
}
```

Then later, at line 170, you can include this flag in options array:

```
$info['options'][] = array(
    'id'        => $value['value_index'],
    'label'     => $value['label'],
    'price'     => $configurablePrice,
    'oldPrice'  => $this->_preparePrice($value['pricing_value'],          
    $value['is_percent']),
    'products'  => $productsIndex,
    'stock'     => $inStock
);
```

It did fine for me.